# Can we make repetitive API calls from reactjs without other components getting disturbed

Tags: reactjs, websocket, routes, react-router, axios

I have a react js component (table) which needs to do an api call every 30mins and refresh the table data. I dont want other components in the page to be disturbed. Only the table content should be changed without any user intervention. Could someone suggest the best possible approach I can follow.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're fetching the data within the component, and storing the result in the component's state, whats the problem?

Comment: understood. but is using setInterval a good practice? or do you think there is a necessity for using WebSockets?

Comment: `setInterval` is fine to use. There's no need to use websockets here as you know the desired refresh interval. The use case for web sockets would be if the server wants to tell the client to refresh, for example once it receives updated data.

Comment: Note you can also use `setTimeout` since the page is going to reload anyways.